# How to verify if indexes of letter from word matches index of letter from words from list in python?

Tags: python, optimization, time-complexity

I have multiple functions which return a list of words (each function contains words that start with the same letter):

```
def get_a():
    #  ..some code
    return words_a  # words_a contain a list with some words that begin with a 

... # and so on

def get_y():
    #  ..some code
    return words_y  # words_y contain a list with some words that begin with y
```

Output example: `['yahoo', 'yep', 'yellow']`

Now, I have a random word ( I know its `len` and only some letters which are located at specific indexes - I also know these )

Supposing that I have the following `partial_word` (I have `0` instead of the empty spaces):

`partial_word = 00LL0W`

What is the best way of getting a list with words(from all my functions) that will satisfy the following condition:

- all known index letters(in my example `L(position2) L(position3) W(position5`) from the `partial_word` will match at the exact same positions the letters from the words from my functions ?
- another important detail is that each function returns a list with 3-4k words.

Comment: I assume that you are looking for matches that are the same length as `partial_word`. Does each of those functions always return the same word list? There's probably a better way to organize your code rather than having all those different functions, one for each letter.

Comment: Well, in those lists I can have words that will have a bigger length but I am interested in returning only those with the length = `partial_word`. And no, each function might have minor changes as those return lists that have been taken from HTML

Comment: Does each of your `get_` function scan through a given HTML document looking for strings that start with its letter? If so, that's rather inefficient. You should have one function that scans the document & builds all the lists. And for your application it makes more sense to create lists of words of the same length rather than lists of words that start with the same letter. You haven't mentioned _how_ you're scanning this HTML document, but I suspect you could be doing that more efficiently by using a library, eg Beautiful Soup.

Comment: Once you have your lists of words of the same length you could build a string from the appropriate list using `' '.join()`, and then use `re.findall()` to find words that match your `partial_word`; you'd just need to use `.` instead of `0` as the symbol for the unspecified letters.

Answer (score 1):

You may make use of the build-in regular expression library

```
import re

partial_word = '00LL0W'
pattern = '^' + partial_word + '$'
pattern = pattern.replace('0', '\w')

example_word = 'YELLOW'
m = re.match(pattern, example_word)
print m.group(0)
```

Comment: I like this solution but there's two problems with it. 1) it doesn't account for case, you can use `re.I` for case insensitive matching, and 2) it needs to be `if m:` before the print for the cases when it doesn't match otherwise it will throw an error

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to pre-generate a dictionary containing a (position, character) tuple as key and a set of words that have that character at that position. In this case, also grouped by word length.

To find the matching words for a certain mask, just look up the position + character tuple of the known characters and intersect the resulting sets.

The following example loads the word list from a file, but that could be easily changed to load from your get_a/b/c functions:

```
def load_dict(words):
    index = {}
    for word in words:
        sub_index = index.setdefault(len(word), {})
        for i, c in enumerate(word):
            sub_index.setdefault((i, c), set()).add(word)
    return index


def find(index, query):
    sub_index = index.get(len(query), {})
    result_sets = (sub_index.get((i, c), set()) for i, c in enumerate(query) if c != ' ')
    return set.intersection(*result_sets)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open('Downloads/wordsEn.txt') as f:
        index = load_dict(line.strip().lower() for line in f)
    print(find(index, '  ll w'))
```